# How does Puttygen generate an RSA key with your random mouse movement?

Tags: putty

I noticed when trying to make an RSA key on PuttyGen it said this:

[image]

How does the random mouse movement help to make the key? If I tried to just keep my cursor still when it asked me to "generate randomness", would the key be less random?

Comment: [Seems like you didn't even search on the site you've posted on originally...](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8705)

Comment: “How does the random mouse movement help to make the key?” - Computers are bad a random. Humans are better at random than computers. Computers “randomly generating” numbers based on mouse movements produces what is close to a random number. Progress of your key won’t happen without mouse movements

Comment: How about: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46864/where-do-key-generation-algorithms-take-the-randomness-from